# TTTabItem in three20 icon not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I have been trying to get TTTabItem to work with images. And I dug up
that you can set the icon to an image file.
This is my implemenation:

```
    TTTabItem *tab1 = [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item 1"]
```

autorelease];
        tab1.icon = @"bundle://icon_eat_min.png";
        filterBar.tabItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                  tab1,
                                                  nil];
        [scrollView addSubview:filterBar];

However, my icon doesn't even appear. I even search through this
group:

http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/f879f6643...

and override  the rounded style. But I am just contemplating why would
you have an something you can set and not have it work? or am i doing
this badly

Comment: three20 has a dedicated stackexchange website for help... please try that resource instead for people with more knowledge about this subject: http://three20.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `tabStyle` for `TTTabBar`

```
TTTabBar *bankTabs = [[TTTabStrip alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 80, 302, 40)];
[bankTabs setTabStyle:@"launcherButtonImage:"];
```